# how to make mouseenter function with fade in effect and stays there

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter

I want to create a tab and when someone hover on that tab someway below a new ul items should display with fade in and fade out effect. Till now I have used mouseenter and the new diplay items should stay there to choose other options.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="sector-nav">
<li><a href="#" class="residential-main">Residential</a></li>
<li><a href="#"class="commercial-main">Commerical</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Private</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="res-pro residential-pro">
<li><a href="#">rProject 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">rProject 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">rProject 3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="com-pro commercial-pro">
<li><a href="#">cProject 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">cProject 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">cProject 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('.residential-main').mouseenter(function() { $('.residential-pro').show(); }); $('.residential-main').mouseleave(function () { $('.residential-pro').hide(); }); }); 

$(document).ready(function() { $('.commercial-main').mouseenter(function() { $('.commercial-pro').show(); }); $('.commercial-main').mouseleave(function () { $('.commercial-pro').hide(); }); });
```

See **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tEMQj/)**

Comment: A fiddle is great, but you should always include your code in the answer as well in case jsfiddle goes down.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan will do keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need javascript for this as you can do it using CSS only with the `:hover` psuedo selector.

First you need to make the related `ul` elements children of their parent `li`:

```
<ul class="sector-nav">
    <li> 
        <a href="#" class="residential-main">Residential</a>
        <ul class="res-pro residential-pro">
            <li><a href="#">rProject 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">rProject 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">rProject 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <a href="#" class="commercial-main">Commerical</a>
        <ul class="com-pro commercial-pro">
            <li><a href="#">cProject 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">cProject 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">cProject 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Private</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then amend the following selectors to hide/show the relevant `ul` elements on hover:

```
.sector-nav > li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #999;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.sector-nav li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.sector-nav > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/tEMQj/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The better way would be to use CSS. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ymsE2/6/) a with fadeIn animation example.

```
.fadeIn {
        border: 1px solid #48484A;
        font-size: 18px;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition : all 2s ease-out;
        -moz-transition : all 2s ease-out;
        -o-transition : all 2s ease-out;
        transition : all 2s ease-out;
    }
    .thisText:hover .fadeIn {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

But since your are using JQuery, you can also use his fadein function which provide animation.

Here is an example from the JQuery documentation:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>fadeIn demo</title>
<style>
p {
position: relative;
width: 400px;
height: 90px;
}
div {
position: absolute;
width: 400px;
height: 65px;
font-size: 36px;
text-align: center;
color: yellow;
background: red;
padding-top: 25px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
display: none;
}
span {
display: none;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Let it be known that the party of the first part
and the party of the second part are henceforth
and hereto directed to assess the allegations
for factual correctness... (<a href="#">click!</a>)
<div><span>CENSORED!</span></div>
</p>
<script>
$( "a" ).click(function() {
$( "div" ).fadeIn( 3000, function() {
$( "span" ).fadeIn( 100 );
});
return false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

See the doc for more examples ([JQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use js, your solution is very close.
Just replace jquery show,hide with fadeIn and fadeOut respectively and initially hide the elements from css. However you also need to modify your html, so that children are presented under their parents.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="sector-nav">
    <li class="residential-main"><a href="#">Residential</a><ul class="res-pro residential-pro">
            <li><a href="#">rProject 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">rProject 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">rProject 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="commercial-main"><a href="#" >Commerical</a>

        <ul class="com-pro commercial-pro">
            <li><a href="#">cProject 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">cProject 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">cProject 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Private</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 .sector-nav li {
    display: inline;
}

.residential-pro , .commercial-pro{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    padding:0;
}

.residential-pro li, .commercial-pro li{
    display:block;
}
```

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.residential-main,.residential-pro').mouseenter(function () {
        $('.residential-pro').stop(false,true).offset({left:$('.residential-main').offset().left}).fadeIn();
    });
    $('.residential-main').mouseleave(function () {
        $('.residential-pro').stop(false,true).fadeOut();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.commercial-main,.commercial-pro').mouseenter(function () {
        $('.commercial-pro').stop(false,true).offset({left:$('.commercial-main').offset().left}).fadeIn();
    });
    $('.commercial-main').mouseleave(function () {
        $('.commercial-pro').stop(false,true).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tEMQj/7/

Comment: how can I make .commercial-pro stays there so I can click on cProject 1 or cProject 2 or cProject 3

Comment: @user2904068 a little tweaking is required let me have a look and i'll update the answer. I'll also modify the layout a bit as well.

Comment: @user2904068 updated answer with a rough solution, few modifications based on your approach.

Comment: i want the corporate pro and residential pro at the same place

Comment: @user2904068 do you mean that you need to keep the html that you initialy had? If yes then this could work http://jsfiddle.net/tEMQj/8/    if no, please explain because i don't understan what you mean.

Comment: yes  i want to keep the initial html as it is so that commercial-pro and residential-pro opens at the same place and when someone clicks on the project 1 , project 2 and project 3 there images opens on the right side and so.